# Django not migrating CharField with choices properly

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-migrations

I have a model `Car` with a CharField `color`, that has the choices of `white`, `black` and `blue`.

```
class Car(models.Model):

    WHITE = "White"
    BLACK = "Black"
    BLUE = "Blue"

    COLOR_CHOICES = (
        (WHITE, "White"),
        (BLACK, "Black"),
        (BLUE, "Blue"),
    )

    ...

    color = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=COLOR_CHOICES, default=BLUE)
```

I already have created `Car` objects with a color. Now when I introduce a change to the choices (e.g. change BLUE to RED in all occurences, as well as in the default) and run the migrations, the `Car` objects of color BLUE that already exist **do not** get migrated to RED. And that's where the weirdness begins:

1. When I use the django shell to check the objects, they appear as Car.BLUE (the choice that no longer exists).
2. When I inspect the objects in the Django Admin, they appear as Car.WHITE.
3. When I create a new object, it works - it becomes Car.RED automatically (picks up the default).

Questions:

- Are there any specific steps that I missed when migrating choices for the CharField?
- Why could this weird behavior be happening and how can I safely fix?
- Do I have to manually (or through a script) fix the data?

I expect upon migration all existing Car.BLUE objects to migrate to Car.RED when I run the migrations, because this is the new default value. I tried to manually create a new object and it picks up the new default RED color. I also tried to manually change an existing object from BLUE to RED, which is also fine. There were no errors when applying the migrations.

*Django version - 4.1.5
DB - PostgreSQL*

Comment: Django will not alter choices, in fact as far as I know, most migration backends do not care about the `choices` at all. Strictly speaking, it is possible to write a backend that would care, but likely not worth the effort.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks for the information. So does that mean I would have to manually (or through a script/command) go through the objects and change the field values?

Comment: you can make a data migration to indeed manipulate the database, such that `red` becomes `blue` (if I understand it correctly?)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, thank you, I just did a migration script and it worked like a charm.

Comment: The best way to this would be to have a new model called CarColor for example. This way you only need to update de CarColor object and all cars would have been updated. You would also have a way to add or remove colors through django admin without having to update the code every time.

Comment: i sometimes wonder if Django is popular or just riddled with complexities that make users ask so many questions....

Comment: @D.L.: I have the idea partly it is because of the dev's team being a bit obsessed with making sure the old sites will keep working, and thus keeping bad design decisions (backwards compatibility). There are a lot of tickets that eventually reach the conclusion "yes, that might have been better, but previous version had this/that, and so we keep it that way".

Comment: Of course backwards compatibility is a valuable thing, but sometimes one can be over-obsessed with this, and unfortunately, such projects eventually become victim of their own success: no longer being able to improve effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django will make migrations if you change the [**`choices=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#choices), in fact Django will make a migration if you change any parameter. But the default migration handler… will not do anything when you change the `choices`. One can implement a different handler, but likely it is not worth the effort.

This thus means that eventually no database changes will be done, so we will have to do this ourselves. If you want to modify data, you can make a [*data migration* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/migrations/#data-migrations). A data migration is just like a normal migration, except that we write how the database should change.

We make a data migration with:

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty app_name
```

In the migration file, we can then construct an update query:

```
from django.db import migrations


def red_to_blue(apps, schema_editor):
    Car = apps.get_model('app_name', 'Car')
    Car.objects.filter(color='Red').update(color='Blue')


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ("app_name", "1234_some_migration"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(red_to_blue),
    ]
```

If we then migrate, it will run the `red_to_blue` function, and migrate the data in the database.